# Cant Connect/Ping to Management Console on Cisco SG200-50 after Connecting networking

Tags: cisco, switch

I have two of these switches.  When I have nothing else plugged in and a cable from port 1 to a laptop on the same subnet I can connect fine, however after plugging any additional networking in I loose the ability to either ping or connect to the management page.  Is there any i'm missing here.

p.S I've already confirmed that it is not an ip conflict and have tried plugging a laptop directly into port 1 with the other networking plugged in to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been pulling my hair out with this same problem as well.  I think I finally found the solution and decided to post it in case anyone else is searching the web for it.

1. Go to Administration -> Management Interface -> IPv4 Interface
2. Under "Administrative Default Gateway" change the radio dial to "User
   Defined" and manually enter the IP Address of the gateway the switch
   should use by default.
3. Hit apply and then you should have access.
4. If it works be sure to save your settings permanently.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has a similar issue the solution is to use cisco "findit utility" to identify your switches ip from the dhcp server.

[findit](http://software.cisco.com/download/release.html?mdfid=282833583&softwareid=283453334&release=1.0.0)

After "applying" the network setting you need to take the additional step of saving the configuration settings to the startup configuration file.  Hope that helps